# Problem with Background image not responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to make a background image responsive with media queries,
but the image retains its original size.

I can't see where i am doing it wrong.
I appreciate any help

```css
#wrapper{
   background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1500x1000) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width:1201) {
  #wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1300x900);
  }
}

@media (max-width:1200px) and (min-width:901) {
  #wrapper{
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/900x750);
  }
}

@media (max-width:900px) and (min-width:601) {
  #wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800x650);
  }
}

/* For mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper{
    
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500x405);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

</div
```

Comment: Change your ```background``` declaration to the following: ```background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1500x1000) center center/cover no-repeat fixed;```

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the HTML reveals that your `background` property is invalid. Try

```
#wrapper{
   /* mobile first this image and move to wherever you intended this one */
   background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1500x1000) center center no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

The rest of your queries could use some cleanup

```
/* For mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper{
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500x405);
  }
}

@media (min-width:601px) {
  #wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800x650);
  }
}

@media (min-width:901px) {
  #wrapper{
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/900x750);
  }
}

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  #wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1300x900);
  }
}
```